# Qt/C++: identifying the parent widget in the event handler (signal)

Tags: qt, events, parent, signals

I'm building a Qt app. In the event handler I want to access the widget that fired the event.

You can do this in the event filter method by casting the QObject parameter:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    MyWidget* widget= static_cast<MyWidget*>(obj);
    ...
}
```

But how can I do that inside a signal method? For example, a listview onclick signal:

```
void MainWindow::listView_Click(QModelIndex index)
{
     QListView* view = // ????
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [QObject::sender()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender).

```
void MainWindow::listView_Click(QModelIndex index)
{
    QListView* view = qobject_cast<QListView* >(sender());
}
```

Comment: Thank you too. Very fast response, and exactly what I need.

Answer (score 4):

The object that sent a signal is available with the [`sender`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#sender) QObject method when you're inside a slot.